# Непонятная запись данных в массив на языке python, как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

[image: Как сохраняется массив]
Язык python, информация в массив записывается в виде "пирамидки"

```
from selenium import webdriver

urls = []
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://63rabota.ru/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82")

url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='f16 bold']//a")

for i in url:
    a = i.get_attribute('href')
    url = {
        'href': a
    }
    urls.append(url)
    print(urls)


driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всё норм, вы видите промежуточные результаты формирования списка. выведите принт из цикла и будете видеть только конечный результат-последнюю строчку из вашего скриншота.

```
from selenium import webdriver

urls = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://63rabota.ru/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82")

url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='f16 bold']//a")

for i in url:
    a = i.get_attribute('href')
    url = {
        'href': a
    }
    urls.append(url)
print(urls)

driver.quit()
```